# Toast notification from theme

Tags: html, sass, notifications, toastr, bootstrap-toast

I am using a theme made with bootstrap and sass for my webapp.

I am not very familiar with bootstrap and sass.

I need to know how to get the code to insert on my webapp.

[You can see the notification example builder here](https://demo.dashboardpack.com/architectui-html-free/components-notifications.html)

[And more info abou the theme here](https://github.com/DashboardPack/architectui-html-theme-free)

So... I need set a toast notification and use it on this function (for the alert):

```
function validarNombre () {
    var tituloAlbm = document.querySelector("#dni").value;
    console.log(tituloAlbm);
    if (tituloAlbm == "" ) {
            alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
            return false;
    } else if (tituloAlbm !== null){
        add();
    }
}
```

I know that is a very vague question, but I am really stuck on this...

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

I like Alertify JS as I have used it.

You will just need to call the Alertify via CDN or from a static folder and call that in the script.

You can check the demo here on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcsj7oye/)

Check the default notification section here: https://alertifyjs.com/

You can use these properties

```
alertify.alert('Ready!');

alertify.success('Success message');

alertify.error('Success message');
```